# Setup multiple databases with Padrino + mysql

Tags: mysql, activerecord, padrino

How to setup multiple databases for padrino + mysql web app. I already try "establish_connection" with activerecord. I found database not found problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this depends on the ORM you use (activerecord in your case?). There is `config/database.rb` to get you started. I know that DataMapper has the concept of repositories, which I personally would likely define there and depending on the use-case in the Model-files.